# How to Filter Spam analytics requests

Tags: google-analytics

I am using google analytics and suddenly I started getting high pageviews. I checked the access logs and found no actual requests. Then i confirmed it by removing the analytics script from the site but still i am seeing those pageviews in real time.

The source of traffic is from referral from monetzationking.com.

What has gone wrong and how can i filter that.[image: exeptionally high request on the same url '/']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter it out by creating a filter from the admin panel.

1 Go to the Admin  tab.

2 Under the "View column", select Filters  and click on + Add Filter    Add filter button Google Anlaytics

3 Enter a name.

4 Filter Type: Custom and Exclude

5 Filter Field: select Campaign Source and put in the URL

[This blog](https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/) is a really comprehensive guide to filtering spam.